# На какие сущности (классы) разделить такую задачу, с точки зрения SOLID?

Tags: php, ооп, solid

Требуется импортировать csv-файл с пользователями в CRM-систему.

У этой CRM-системы есть свой API для работы с пользователя (класс с CRUD методами).

Я предполагаю, что нужно разделить на две сущности:

- класс, который будет на вход получать csv-файл, считывать данные, валидировать и возвращать коллекцию DTO-объектов пользователей.
- класс, который на вход получает коллекцию DTO-объектов пользователей, и занимается импортом.

Или как-то по другому лучше было бы и почему? Какие есть предложения ?
Не является ли лишним здесь использовать использовать DTO, а не просто массив ?

Answer (score 0):

Звучит нормально, но если акция разовая - то не стоит заниматься оверинженерингом.

Answer (score 0):

Тогда уж и валидацию тоже отдельным классом сделайте. Вообще как я понимаю вопрос больше по принципу SRP чем по всему SOLID. SRP можно растолковать как: "У класса должна быть только одна причина для изменения". Класс под номером 1 в вашем случаю имеет больше одной причины для изменения.